# How to write a dirac delta symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I mean the squiggle `d_{ij}` Dirac Delta thing but I am not sure how to put the notation for it. Does anyone know?

Comment: `$\delta_{ij}$`?

Comment: I would consider this a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764), since [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) drops out `\delta` as the first choice, and it's easily identifiable in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Just waiting for feedback from @Magpie.

Comment: no @egreg that is a delta.

Comment: Thanks @Werner I found it that way. I will bookmark that site!

Comment: @Magpie: If it is not `\delta`, what is it then? Do you have a reference? I'm looking at this Wikipedia page: [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: I was just about to put it up. Also it was a delta I was thinking that could only be used with derivatives but it is the same one.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article a regular delta is used as well. It is upshape however, so it may look different (you can use package `upgreek` en `\updelta`). Also: most people use `\partial` for derivatives.